# How to get the current suiteName in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Is there any way to get the name of the current suite that is being executed in jasmine/protractor? I would need it to generate some custom reports.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.suite.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is not any. However, nothing stops you from implementing it manually:

```
const suites = {
  suite1: 'suite name',
  suite2: 'suite name',
}

describe(suites.suite1, () => {
  it('test name', () => {
    ...
    myCustomReport(suites.suite1)
  })
})
```

P.S. The syntax is not precise, I don't remember it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var spec = it("name for it", function() {
   console.log(spec.description); // prints "name for it"
});
```

Hope this helps you...